# How to check if a variable contains a rect in Pygame?

Tags: python, variables, pygame, rect

So if I add a rect to a variable like so

```
box = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
```

How do I check if the variable rect holds a `pygame.Rect`? Ideally it would return something similar to this

```
int = 9

#int is not a rect
#box is a rect
```

Comment: I'm wondering when you will need it. if you create variable to keep `Rect` then it should always keep `Rect` - don't mess it. And if you want to keep different objects on list - ie. Player, Enemy, etc. then all of them should have exactly the same methods - `draw`, `update`, etc. instead of `draw_player`, `draw_enemy`, `update_player`, `update_enemy` - and then you don't have to check class to decide if you have to use `draw_player` or `draw_enemy` - you always has to use `draw`.

Comment: Oh I have mine for functions. I have an optional argument for centering, and I want it to automatically center stuff if a rect is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isinstance(object, classinfo)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

> Return `True` if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument [...]

```py
if isinstance(box, pygame.Rect):
    print('is a rect')
else:
    print('is not a rect')
```